# How to Insert unique column data into elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a webcrawler that scrapes Business Names and Business Contact numbers and inserts into ElasticSearch

The problem is i dot **NOT** want duplicate phone numbers inserted into the column

Is there anyway i can achieve this internally in elasticsearch?

If not, is there a better solution than the below steps

> Fetch Record -> Check for Duplicate phone number -> Insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `unique` token filter for this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/analysis-unique-tokenfilter.html

If the phone numbers are put in the same field of one document, then create a tokenizer that should output as tokens each phone number.

And for this tokenizer define a filter of type unique that will keep the unique tokens. Something around these lines:

```
  "analyzer": {
    "numbers": {
      "tokenizer": "[whatever]",
      "filter": [
        ...,
        "unique"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you help out in this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400041/unique-filter-to-elastic-search-column-not-working-duplicate-items-inserted