# Unique Filter to Elastic Search Column not working (duplicate items inserted)

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I've modified my `contactNumber` field to have a `unique` filter

by updating the index settings as follows

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-index2/_settings -d '
{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "unique_keyword_analyzer":{
         "only_on_same_position":"true",
                 "filter":"unique"
              }
           }
        }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "business":{
        "properties":{
           "contactNumber":{
              "analyzer":"unique_keyword_analyzer",
              "type":"string"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

A sample Item looks like this,

```
doc_type:"Business"

contactNumber:"(+12)415-3499"
name:"Sam's Pizza"
address:"Somewhere on earth"
```

The Filter does not work, as duplicate items are inserted, I'd like **NO** two documents having the same contactNumber

in the above, I've also set `only_on_same_position` -> `true` so that existing duplicate values would be truncated/deleted

What am i doing wrong in the settings?

Comment: How does the usual document look like? (one that has duplicates)

Comment: @AndreiStefan Edited to add a sample document, a duplicate document always has the same contact number &name but with a minor difference in address

Comment: I don't get it. `unique` strips duplicate tokens from the same field. For example: `"contactNumber": "(+12)415-3499 (+12)415-3499 (+12)415-3499"` will end up being indexed in ES as `(+12)415-3499` and that's it. You are talking about multiple documents, not multiple "same" values in the same **field** of **one document**.

Comment: So, what is the actual use case here?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I understand and could you tell me how i may avoid having 2 records with duplicate contact numbers

Comment: @AndreiStefan I'm trying a build a business directory with analytics (eventually) and i require leveraging elasticsearch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83177/discussion-between-wolfgang-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: That's something Elasticsearch couldn't help you out of the box... you need to make this uniqueness functionality available in your app. The only idea that I can think of is to have the phone number as the `_id` of the document itself and whenever you insert/update something ES will use the `contactNumber` as `_id` and it will associate that document with the one that already exists or create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's something Elasticsearch couldn't help you out of the box... you need to make this uniqueness functionality available in your app. The only idea that I can think of is to have the phone number as the `_id` of the document itself and whenever you insert/update something ES will use the `contactNumber` as `_id` and it will associate that document with the one that already exists or create a new one.

For example:

```
PUT /test-index2
{
  "mappings": {
    "business": {
      "_id": {
        "path": "contactNumber"
      }, 
      "properties": {
        "contactNumber": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "keyword"
        },
        "address": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you index something:

```
POST /test-index2/business
{
  "contactNumber": "(+12)415-3499",
  "address": "whatever 123"
}
```

Getting it back:

```
GET /test-index2/business/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

It looks like this:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test-index2",
            "_type": "business",
            "_id": "(+12)415-3499",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "contactNumber": "(+12)415-3499",
               "address": "whatever 123"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

You see there that the `_id` of the document is the phone number itself. If you want to change or insert another document (the address is different, there is a new field - `whatever_field` - but the `contactNumber` is the same):

```
POST /test-index2/business
{
  "contactNumber": "(+12)415-3499",
  "address": "whatever 123 456",
  "whatever_field": "whatever value"
}
```

Elasticserach "updates" the existing document and responds back with:

```
{
   "_index": "test-index2",
   "_type": "business",
   "_id": "(+12)415-3499",
   "_version": 2,
   "created": false
}
```

`created` is `false`, this means the document has been updated, not created. `_version` is `2` which again says that the document has been updated. And the `_id` is the phone number itself which indicate this is the document that has been updated.

Looking again in the index, ES stores this:

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "test-index2",
        "_type": "business",
        "_id": "(+12)415-3499",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "contactNumber": "(+12)415-3499",
           "address": "whatever 123 456",
           "whatever_field": "whatever value"
        }
     }
  ]
```

So, the new field is there, the address has changed, the `contactNumber` and `_id` are exactly the same.

Comment: Detailed Explanation, Thanks!